# How to extract arbitrary 2D slice from 3D volume using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, volume, slice

I'm using Scipy for rendering planes from 3D data (vector 200x200x200).
I can specify the wanted plane by 2 vectors or vector and an angle.
I want to extract such an arbitrary slice from this 3D volume.
I found how to do it in Matlab:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/slice.html
How do I do it in Scipy?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) to rotate your 3d array to whatever angle you want (it uses spline interpolation) then you can take a slice out of it.

Comment: It rotates the entire volume, but I only need specific slice.
Also, it's hard to tell the result polygon vertices

Comment: @Shahar Yifrah - yes, it rotates the whole volume, then you take the slice out of it.

Comment: It's a waste to rotate the entire volume for just a slice.
The second point: the slice of a box can be some polygon which I want to have its shape in order to draw it.
The rotated volume would contain some padding for the source-less ends.

Comment: @Shahar Yifrah - If you figure out an alternative way, please post it here, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Sure.. also - see the link to matlab code I put in my question

Answer (score 3):

def extract_slice(data, triplet):
    """
    Algorithm:
    1. find intersections of the plane with the data box edges
    2. for these pts, find axis-oriented b-box
    3. find the "back" trans (A,T) from R2 to R3, like X' = AX + T
       use (0,0), (0,h), (w,0) which are easy to calculate
    4. use the trans (with trilinear-interpolation) for every value in the 2D (w,h) image
    """

I will release the code properly in a few months I believe as a part of this project.

Comment: I am interested in doing this. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I was addressing a similar task as the OP so I came up with this code based on **numpy** (not scipy) to extract any given slice from a volume given a position vector of any point of the plane and three orthogonal orientation vectors.

I apologise for the length of my answer, but given the complexity of the problem at hand i thought it would be better to give this amount of detail.

For my particular problem these vectors were defined in mm instead of pixels so the spacing (i.e. distance between two consecutive volume pixels at each direction) was also used as input. I have used a nearest neighbour approach to interpolate the subpixel points of the slice.

`reslice_volume (volume, spacing, o1, o2, n, pos)`

The main steps behind this algorithm are as follow. Note that i use plane and slice interchangeably:

**1.** Get **intersection lines** between the desired plane and the bounds of the volume.

```
    def PlaneBoundsIntersectionsLines (n, pos):
  """Outputs points and vectors defining the lines that the view creates by intersecting the volume's bounds.
      Input:
        Normal vector of the given plane and the coords of a point belonging to the plane.
      Output:
        normals_line, points_line
        """
    def intersectionPlanePlane(n1,p1,n2,p2):
        # Get direction of line
        nout = np.cross(n1.reshape((1,3)),n2.reshape((1,3))).reshape(3,1)
        nout = normalizeLength(nout)
        M =  np.concatenate((n1.reshape(1,3),n2.reshape(1,3)), axis=0)
        b = np.zeros((2,1))
        # print(n1.shape, p1.shape)
        b[0,0]=np.dot(n1,p1)
        b[1,0]=np.dot(n2,p2)
        pout,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(M,b, rcond=None)
        return pout, nout
      # ... For each face
      normalFaces = np.concatenate((np.eye(3,3),np.eye(3,3)), axis = 1)
      pointsFaces = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0], [379.9872, 379.9872, 169.5], [379.9872, 379.9872, 169.5], [379.9872, 379.9872, 169.5]]).transpose()
      points_line = np.zeros((3,6))
      normals_line = np.zeros((3,6))
      for face in range(6):
        n1 = normalFaces[:,face].reshape(3,)
        p1 = pointsFaces[:,face].reshape(3,)
        pout, nout = intersectionPlanePlane(n1,p1,n,pos)
        points_line[:,face] = pout.reshape((3,))
        normals_line[:,face] = nout.reshape((3,))
      return normals_line, points_line
```

**2.** Get **intersection points between these lines** that are close enough to the borders of the volume to be considered corners of the intersection between the plane and the volume.

```
def FindPlaneCorners(normals_line, points_line):
  """Outputs the points defined by the intersection of the input lines that 
  are close enough to the borders of the volume to be considered corners of the view plane.
      Input:
        Points and vectors defining lines
      Output:
        p_intersection, intersecting_lines
        """
  def intersectionLineLine(Up,P0,Uq,Q0):
    # Computes the closest point between two lines
    # Must be column points
    b = np.zeros((2,1))
    b[0,0] = -np.dot((P0-Q0),Up)
    b[1,0] = -np.dot((P0-Q0),Uq)
    A = np.zeros((2,2))
    A[0,0] = np.dot(Up,Up)
    A[0,1] = np.dot(-Uq,Up)
    A[1,0] = np.dot(Up,Uq)
    A[1,1] = np.dot(-Uq,Uq)
    if ( np.abs(np.linalg.det(A)) < 10^(-10) ):
      point = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]).reshape(3,1)
    else:
      lbd ,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b, rcond=None)
      # print('\n')
      # print(lbd)
      P1 = P0 + lbd[0]*Up;
      Q1 = Q0 + lbd[1]*Uq;
      point = (P1+Q1)/2;
    return point
  # ... ... Get closest point for every possible pair of lines and select only the ones inside the box
  npts = 0
  p_intersection = []
  intersecting_lines = []
  # ... Get all possible pairs of lines
  possible_pairs = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(np.linspace(0,5,6), 2)))
  for pair in possible_pairs:
    k = int(pair[0])
    j = int(pair[1])
    Up = normals_line[:,k]
    P0 = points_line[:,k]
    Uq = normals_line[:,j]
    Q0 = points_line[:,j]
    closest_point = intersectionLineLine(Up,P0,Uq,Q0)
    epsilon = 2.2204e-10
    # ... ... Is point inside volume? Is it close to the border?
    if closest_point[0] <= 379.9872 + epsilon and closest_point[0] >= 0 - epsilon and \
                closest_point[1] <= 379.9872 + epsilon and closest_point[1] >= 0 - epsilon and \
                closest_point[2] <= 169.5 + epsilon and closest_point[2] >= 0 - epsilon:
      # ... ...  Is it close to the border? 25 mm?
      th = 25
      if 379.9872 - closest_point[0] <= th or closest_point[0] - 0 <= th or \
          379.9872 - closest_point[1] <= th or closest_point[1] - 0 <= th or \
          169.5 - closest_point[2] <= th or closest_point[2] - 0 <= th:
        # print('It is close to teh border')
        npts += 1
        p_intersection.append(closest_point)
        intersecting_lines.append([k,j])

  p_intersection = np.array(p_intersection).transpose()

  return p_intersection, intersecting_lines
```

**3.** **Transform the points found into the slice's reference frame** (sRF) (we can center the RF arbitrarily within the slice plane).

```
dim = volume.shape
  # ... Get intersection lines between plane and volume bounds
  normals_line, points_line = PlaneBoundsIntersectionsLines (n, pos)

  # ... Get intersections between generated lines to get corners of view plane
  p_intersection, intersecting_lines = FindPlaneCorners (normals_line, points_line)

  # ... Calculate parameters of the 2D slice
  # ... ... Get corners of slice from volume RF (vrf) to slice RF (srf) - in this case centered in the middle of teh slice
  # ... ... ... Define T_vrf2srf
  Pose_slice_vrf = M_creater(o1,o2,n,pos)
  # ... ... ... Apply transform
  p_intersection_slicerf = np.zeros(p_intersection.shape)
  for corner in range(p_intersection.shape[1]):
    pt_arr = np.concatenate((p_intersection[:,corner],np.ones((1,))) ,axis = 0).reshape((4,1))
    p_intersection_slicerf[:,corner] = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(Pose_slice_vrf), pt_arr)[:-1].reshape((3,))
```

**4.** **Get minimum x and y coordinates across these points** and define a corner point that will be used as origin of the plane/slice. **Transform this origin point back to the volume's RF** (vRF) and **define a new transform matrix** that shifts RF from vRF to a sRF but now centered on said origin point.

**5.** From these inslice points coordinates we can **determine the size of the slice** and then use it to generate all possible inslice indexes of the target slice.

```
 # ... ... Get slice size based on corners and spacing
  spacing_slice = [1,1,8]
  min_bounds_slice_xy = np.min(p_intersection_slicerf,axis=1)
  max_bounds_slice_xy = np.max(p_intersection_slicerf,axis=1)
  size_slice_x = int(np.ceil((max_bounds_slice_xy[0] - min_bounds_slice_xy[0] - 1e-6) / spacing_slice[0]))
  size_slice_y = int(np.ceil((max_bounds_slice_xy[1] - min_bounds_slice_xy[1] - 1e-6) / spacing_slice[1]))
  slice_size = [size_slice_x, size_slice_y, 1]
  print('slice_size')
  print(slice_size)

  # ... ... Get corner in slice coords and redefine transform mat - make corner origin of the slice
  origin_corner_slice = np.array([min_bounds_slice_xy[0],min_bounds_slice_xy[1],0])
  pt_arr = np.concatenate((origin_corner_slice,np.ones((1,))) ,axis = 0).reshape((4,1))
  origin_corner_slice_vrf = np.matmul(Pose_slice_vrf, pt_arr)[:-1].reshape((3,))
  Pose_slice_origin_corner_vrf = M_creater(o1,o2,n,origin_corner_slice_vrf)

  # ... ... Get every possible inslice coordinates
  xvalues = np.linspace(0,size_slice_x-1,size_slice_x)
  yvalues = np.linspace(0,size_slice_y-1,size_slice_y)
  zvalues = np.linspace(0,0,1)
  xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)
  xx = xx.transpose()
  yy = yy.transpose()
  zz = np.zeros(xx.shape)
  inslice_coords = np.concatenate((xx.reshape(-1,1), yy.reshape(-1,1), zz.reshape(-1,1)), axis = 1)
```

**6.** Next step is to use the newly defined transform matrix (step 4) to **map every possible inslice index to the volume's reference frame**.

```
# ... ... Map every point of slice into volume's RF
  inslice_coords_vrf = np.zeros(inslice_coords.shape)
  for coord_set in range(inslice_coords.shape[0]):
    pt_arr = np.concatenate((inslice_coords[coord_set,:],np.ones((1,))) ,axis = 0).reshape((4,1))
    inslice_coords_vrf[coord_set,:] = np.matmul(Pose_slice_origin_corner_vrf, pt_arr)[:-1].reshape((3,))
```

**7.** We now have **all the vRF coordinates that the slice encompasses** that should be promptly **converted into pixel values** by dividing them by the respective **spacing**. At this step we find that we end up with non-integer pixel values as the slices passes through subpixel locations of the volume. We round the pixel value to its nearest integer - *nearest neighbour interpolation*.

```
# ... ... ... Convert to pixel coord - here we used teh resampled spacing
  inslice_coords_vrf_px = inslice_coords_vrf.copy()
  inslice_coords_vrf_px[:,0] = inslice_coords_vrf[:,0] / spacing[0]
  inslice_coords_vrf_px[:,1] = inslice_coords_vrf[:,1] / spacing[1]
  inslice_coords_vrf_px[:,2] = inslice_coords_vrf[:,2] / spacing[2]

  # ... ... Interpolate pixel value at each mapped point - nearest neighbour int
  # ... ... ... Convert pixel value to its closest existing value in the volume
  inslice_coords_vrf_px = np.round(inslice_coords_vrf_px, 0).astype(int)
```

**8.** Next, we determine which pixels of the slice are actually within the bounds of the volume and get their values. Pixels outside volume are padded to 0.

```
# ... ... Find slice voxels within volume bounds
  in_mask = np.zeros((inslice_coords_vrf_px.shape[0], 1))
  idx_in = []
  for vox in range(in_mask.shape[0]):
    if not np.any(inslice_coords_vrf_px[vox,:]<0) and \
                  inslice_coords_vrf_px[vox,0]<dim[0] and \
                  inslice_coords_vrf_px[vox,1]<dim[1] and \
                  inslice_coords_vrf_px[vox,2]<dim[2]:
      in_mask[vox] = 1
      idx_in.append(vox)
  idx_in = np.array(idx_in)
  # ... ... Get pixel value from volume based on interpolated pixel indexes
  extracted_slice = np.zeros((inslice_coords_vrf_px.shape[0], 1))
  for point in range(inslice_coords_vrf_px.shape[0]):
    if point in idx_in:
      vol_idx = inslice_coords_vrf_px[point,:]
      extracted_slice[point] = volume[vol_idx[0], vol_idx[1], vol_idx[2]]
  # ... ... Reshape to slice shape
  extracted_slice = extracted_slice.reshape((slice_size[0], slice_size[1]))
```

I added a plot for extra clarity. Here the volume is defined by the bounding box in black. Line intersections of the slice with the planes defined by the faces of the box/volume in dotted orange. In blue the intersection points between the previous lines. Points in pink belong to the slice and the orange ones belong to the slice and are within the volume.

In my case i was dealing with MRI volumes, so as example I added my resulting slice from the volume.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]